# demands from the user text and return two the most repeating letter from it

Tags: r

```
a <- as.character(readline(" Please input a text:    "))

most_repeated_character <- function(x) {
    tab <- table(strsplit(x, '')[[1]])
    names(tab)[tab == max(tab)]
}

print(most_repeated_character(a))
```

I need help to return two most repeating characters from text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses a frequency table.  We can first remove whitespace from the input using `sub`:

```r
x <- "Hello World"
x <- gsub("\\s+", "", x)
lets <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
tbl <- sort(table(lets), decreasing=TRUE)
paste0("most frequently occurring: (", names(tbl)[1], ", ", tbl[[1]], ")")
paste0("second most frequently occurring: (", names(tbl)[2], ", ", tbl[[2]], ")")
```

This prints:

```
[1] "most frequently occurring: (l, 3)"         # 'l' occur 3 times
[1] "second most frequently occurring: (o, 2)"  # 'o' occurs 2 times
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to get rid of the space if the user input a text with space?

Comment: It seems not working.
Please input a text:     i love art 
> lets <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
> lets <- gsub("\\s+", "", lets)
> tbl <- sort(table(lets), decreasing=TRUE)
> paste0("most frequently occurring: (", names(tbl)[1], ", ", tbl[[1]], ")")
[1] "most frequently occurring: (, 2)"
> paste0("second most frequently occurring: (", names(tbl)[2], ", ", tbl[[2]], ")")
[1] "second most frequently occurring: (a, 1)"
It still counts the space as character.

Comment: It will still be working if the input did not have space. But if it have space then it counts space as character. So that the problem I still have now. Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: @HàoNguyễnHưng Sorry, I gave you bad advice.  You should run `sub` on the user input itself, check the updated answer.